# compare the results of two columns in a table c# mssqlserver

Tags: c#, select

I#m working with VisualStudio 2013 Premium C# and a MSSQLServer

I want to order by EndDate

Then (with a loop) I want to find out when StartDate of the next column in my table is lower than the EndDate of the current column

StartDate and EndDate are Seconds

Example

StartDate

```
1 
2 
3 
1 
6 
7 
7
```

EndDate

```
3 
3 
4 
5 
7 
8 
10
```

Here the program count until EndDate 5
Because  6<=5 
StartDate<= EndDate.

If I Count my results:

4

3

Then I want to find out the maximum of the list 
In this case 4

Background: I want to find out in which second  I get the Maximum of calls.

Can anybody help me out with ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your explanation, but answering your question

> I want to find out in which second I get the Maximum of calls.

```
void Main()
{   
    var startDate = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 7, 7 };
    var endDate = new [] { 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10 };
    var maxCallsCount = 0;
    var secondAtMaxCallsCount = 0;

    foreach (var second in Enumerable.Range(startDate.Min(), 
                                            endDate.Max() - startDate.Min() + 1))
    {
        var callsCount = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < startDate.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (startDate[i] <= second && second <= endDate[i])
            {
                ++callsCount;
            }
        }

        if (callsCount > maxCallsCount)
        {
            maxCallsCount = callsCount;
            secondAtMaxCallsCount = second;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Max calls count is " + maxCallsCount + 
                      " at " + secondAtMaxCallsCount + " second");
}
```

Comment: That is what I wanted, I even don´t need the secondAtMaxCallsCount.

Comment: I used now List<int?> to pass my parameters. But now I´m not really sure how to implement the Enumerable.Range. Is this the right way:

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the Problems with the parameters with `List<int?>`
but now I´m not sure how to implement the Range und Loop. 
Is the following right?

```
   foreach (var second in Enumerable.Range((int)beginningDate.FirstOrDefault(),
                                            (int)endDate.Last() - (int)beginningDate.FirstOrDefault() +1))
            {
                var callsCount = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < beginningDate.Last(); ++i)
                {
                    if (beginningDate[i] <= second && second <= endDate[i])
                    {
                        ++callsCount;
                    }
                }

                if (callsCount > maxCallsCount)
                {
                    maxCallsCount = callsCount;
                }
            }
```

I allways get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException-Exception. 
Index is out of range.

Comment: It's hard to follow your explanations, can you please post your code on https://dotnetfiddle.net so I can see what error do you get?